# Which weapons have extended magazines available for unlock?

Tags: battlefield-3

For example most of the LMG's do. Some SMG's do. Has anybody compiled a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By going through all the weapons in battlelog, the following weapons can have extended magazines attached to them.

- All Support weapons (except for the QBB-95 and MG-36).
- The PP-2000, PDW-R, MP7, AS Val and M5K.
- All Shotguns.

So not many at all, and all of the ones that can are either a LMG, SMG, or a Shotgun.

Answer (score 0):

In all of the weapon classes I have come to see, every gun uses a secondary slot for extended mags except for three weapons in the support class.

Comment: Welcome to site, Briyor. :) Can you please be more specific with your answer and include which three guns? Also, please avoid irrelevant information in your answers.